# Delete user folder on windows using ansible

Tags: ansible, directory

Unable to delete user directory using ansible win_file module, there is no error but it is not deleting

```
  win_file:
    path: C:\Users\myuser
    state: absent
    force: yes

Below one also I have tried where it tries to delete the current user folder and returns directory in use cos it is trying to delete the current user folder

- name: Remove directory structur
  win_file:
    path: C:\Users
    name: myuser
    state: absent
    force: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to delete the profile using a tool designed specifically for that purpose.  This will help avoid cluttering the Windows registry and running into any number of other issues.

Check out this Ansible community module:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_user_profile_module.html

```
- name: Remove a profile for a still-existing account
  community.windows.win_user_profile:
    username: myuser
    state: absent
```

If the account has already been deleted, you need to specify 'name' instead of 'username':

```
- name: Remove a profile for a deleted account
  community.windows.win_user_profile:
    name: myuser
    state: absent
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, but the server reboot cannot be performed as it is a disruptive activity for other test users and everytime it has to go through change :(

Comment: I think you still should be able to do this using the win_user_profile module (even without a reboot).